# Html 5 section behaving out of the track

Tags: html

I am new to html 5 and I am learning this, the problem which i faced is section is not applying my given class I dont know what is the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <header role="banner">
        <hgroup class="main_container">
        <h1 id="logo"></h1>
        </hgroup>
        </header>
    <nav>
        <ul class="main_container">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Initatives</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Publications</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Green Homes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Renewble Energy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Global Warming</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lives</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="main_container">
        <h1>Why this kolaveri dee? </h1>
    </section>  
</body>
</html>
```

======css====

```
    body
{
    margin:0;
    background:#F6F5F1;
    font-family:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
h1
{
    margin:0;
}
.main_container
{
    width:950px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
header
{
    background:#fdf7e7;
    padding:10px;
}
#logo
{
    background:url(../images/logo.jpg);
    height:72px;
    width:302px;
}
nav
{
    background:#e9ebb0;
    height:41px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #c4c297;
}
nav ul
{
    list-style:none;
    background:#577a70;
    height:31px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #3c4852;
}
nav ul li
{
    float:left;

}
nav a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:0 20px 0 0;
    margin-right:20px;
    border-right:1px dotted white;
}
nav li:last-child a
{

    border-right:none;
}
nav a:hover
{
    color:#FFFF33;
}
section
{
    height:200px;
    clear:both;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:950px;
    background:#577a70;

}
```

---

[image]

jsfiddle link > http://jsfiddle.net/LNAcV/5/

**Edit** : Everyone thanks for the help i restructured the whole thing and did not found the same issue again. something was wrong in my code I guess now its working fine.

Comment: No problem for me with Opera 12, what browser are you testing with?

Comment: firefox 10.0 latest i guess, now downloading opera 12

Comment: I checked my browser in this http://html5test.com/ every thing goes positive...

Comment: @Veger whoaaa i found the same thing in opera i want section to be spread as navigation see my screen shot

Comment: it's work for me http://jsfiddle.net/LNAcV/6/

Comment: That JSFiddle works fine for me too. Have you got any extensions installed? Maybe your role="banner" is being messed up by Adblock or something?

Comment: nah I dont know what is the issue I have done very basics now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 
**padding:0;**
to the main_container class.

The problem are the generyc styles of the browser

Comment: If that's the case it might be good for Pankaj to consider learning more about CSS reset http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: @jmbertucci Thanks for the recommendations, I am aware of this.:)

Comment: @oleurud thanks for the help i restructured the whole thing and did not found the same issue again. something was wrong in my code I guess