# how to make image can display repeat in div without set height

Tags: html, css

i  have problem like this.

```
#container_index{
    width:100%;
    height:1300px;
    background:url(../img/green%20pattern.jpg);
}
```

in the code above i am set `height 1300px` and nothing problem, i mean image can display and can repeated.
but, if i change the code be (with `height auto`, image can not display):
show me the way to solve my problem. i want the image display without set height.
thanks

```
  #container_index{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background:url(../img/green%20pattern.jpg); 
    }
```

Comment: @sandeep Hi do u know html 5?

Comment: @Jack Why you are asking that ?

Comment: coz i have been through your profile it says that

Comment: @jack Yup i know HTML5. So, there anything regarding HTML5 you want to know

Comment: yes I have asked a question on html 5 I am learning that and stuck in beginning :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189893/html-5-section-behaving-out-of-the-track

Answer (score 0):

When you use `height: auto;` and div is empty, its height will be 0px, meaning, the background won't show up. You might want to set a `min-height`.

Answer (score 0):

Without setting height you can not display the image in table or div,via background coz height is the element which do make sure that there is something which is to be displayed.either give the height of its container or of the image..

if you want to show this image without height you have to call this from html source.this will work fine it doesn't require height and width element

You should read this for more information on images with height and widths.

[Height and width](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/images/_IMG_WIDTH.html)

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

In an empty container you will not see any background image. If you add contents up to the height of bg, you can see the full image, otherwise you will see only the content-height of that bg. If you set a 'min-height' property with the height of bg, you will be able to see the bg without any contents in the container.. Hope you understand :-)

Regards..